# Linksys WRT54G wireless router UPNP unavailable

Tags: networking, nat, upnp

I have UPNP enabled on my router. I found the page where it can be enabled or disabled, and it was already enabled, yet the UPNP diagnostic application I am using does not seem to show this device. (I downloaded and built the project from http://managedupnp.codeplex.com/). I can see my desktop's media server, and that of another Windows 7 desktop, and 2 devices from a wireless range extender I recently got ("RE1000" and "WFADevice"), but I can't see anything that looks like the router. Why not? It's running Firmware version 4.21.4 build 0, Jul. 12, 2011

Comment: A router is a transparent device, UPNP or not. It shouldn't be running any services you'd see via a UPNP client, it should simply and transparently forward the UPNP traffic through itself. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I've heard that UPNP can be used to configure a router to apply NAT traversal so I don't have to manually map ports on the router to an internal IP address. I would expect a wireless range extender to be even more transparent than a router, yet I can see a UPNP device for the range extender, but not the router. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776008(v=vs.85).aspx (I think).

Comment: @Xyon Also, why would my router have a UPnP setting if it's not a UPnP device?

Comment: For the purpose your previous comment outlined, enabling that NAT traversal in a seamless fashion.

Comment: I guess my question has changed, then, and maybe I should post it on StackOverflow.com, but to the extent that a super-user might be interested to know, how does software affect NAT routings so that, for example, my hosting program running on port 1110 causes external requests to port 1110 of my router get to my internal IP address? Usually I have to establish these routings manually, so simply opening a port and listening isn't enough. Is there some UPNP-specific activity a host program needs to perform to "publish" itself to the router?

Comment: @Xyon The article at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal seems to conflict with what you are saying. Routers *can* represent themselves as UPNP devices that control points on the network can manipulate directly.